# How to append class object to list

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

After instantiating a deck (`deck = Deck()`), calling `deck.show_deck()` just prints out "two of diamonds" 52 times. The 'copy' part is as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196956/add-an-object-to-a-python-list), but doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions?

```
import copy
from card import Card

class Deck:

    card_ranks = ['ace','king','queen','jack','ten','nine','eight','seven','six','five','four','three','two']
    card_suites = ['clubs','hearts','spades','diamonds']

    deck = []   

    def __init__(self):
        #create a deck of 52 cards

        for suite in Deck.card_suites:
            for rank in Deck.card_ranks:
                Deck.deck.append(copy.deepcopy(Card(card_rank=rank, card_suite=suite)))



    def show_deck(self):
        for item in Deck.deck:
            print item.get_name()
```

Card:

```
class Card:

    card_name = ''

    def __init__(self, card_rank, card_suite):
        self.card_rank = card_rank.lower()
        self.card_suite = card_suite.lower()
        Card.card_name = card_rank + " of " + card_suite

    def get_name(self):
        return Card.card_name
```

Comment: I would create a temporary list first that contains all the cards then after that deepcopy the temporary list to `deck`

Comment: Would that temporary list go within the init?

Comment: You don't show your `Card` code here, but why do you need a `deepcopy`, particularly if you're instantiating it for the first time? Something isn't right here.

Comment: Card is relatively trivial, but I'll add it in here

Comment: @user2372996 Yes the temporary list would go in `__init__` but I can't help but think there's a design problem here because you really shouldn't need a deepcopy here. As for the cause of why the code in your question doesn't work I'm just trying to get my head around that right now.

Comment: the deepcopy is more of a shot in the dark to try get it to work. Removing it has the same outcome.

Comment: @user2372996, thanks for editing to include the Card class, this is a very good example of why making reproducible examples allows you to get better help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Card` class has a name variable which is shared with all instances of the `Card` class.

When you have:

```
class Card:

    card_name = ''
```

This means that all `Card` objects will have the same name (`card_name`) which is almost surely not what you want.

You have to make the name be part of the instance instead like so:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, card_rank, card_suite):
        self.card_rank = card_rank.lower()
        self.card_suite = card_suite.lower()
        self.card_name = card_rank + " of " + card_suite

    def get_name(self):
        return self.card_name
```

You will find that the `deepcopy` is not needed, nor was it ever needed, but it does show you that `deepcopy` will not allow you to keep different states of class variables.

Further I would recommend you change `Card` to have it's own `__str__` method if you want to print it out:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, card_rank, card_suite):
        self.card_rank = card_rank.lower()
        self.card_suite = card_suite.lower()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} of {1}".format(card_rank, card_suit)
```

This uses the Python language itself to print the class and has the upside that your class will now work properly in print statements and in conversions to strings. So instead of:

```
print some_card.get_name()
```

you could do

```
print some_card
```

Comment: Beat me by 30 sec. Even better: `u'%s of %s' % (card_rank, card_suit)` (as long as you change it everywhere to `card_suit`).

Comment: and here I was thinking `Card` was trivial... thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what shuttle87 said:

```
class Card:

    card_name = ''
```

makes `card_name` a static variable (shared between all instances of that class)

Once you make the variable non-static (by using `self.card_name` in the `__init__` method) you won't have to worry about the copy part as each instance of the card class will have it's own unique name

On that note, the `deck` in Deck is also static in your code.

```
from card import Card

class Deck:
    # these 2 can be static, they never change between copies of the deck class
    card_ranks = ['ace','king','queen','jack','ten','nine','eight','seven','six','five','four','three','two']
    card_suites = ['clubs','hearts','spades','diamonds']

    def __init__(self):
        # this shouldn't be static since you might want to shuffle them 
        # or do other things that make them unique for each deck
        self.cards = []

        for suite in Deck.card_suites:
            for rank in Deck.card_ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(rank, suite))

    def show_deck(self):
        for item in self.cards:
            print item
```

---

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suite):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suite = suite

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suite
```

---

```
#! python2

from deck import Deck

def main():
    deck = Deck()

    deck.show_deck()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
ace of clubs
king of clubs
queen of clubs
jack of clubs
...
```

Comment: I don't believe the copy will actually help fix the issue with the state stored in the class variable, I think you are addressing an important upvote worthy part of an answer by mentioning that so you may wish to test this out. Also to format code inline in the text of your answer you can use backticks .

Comment: Thanks for the format help. I tested the code above (copied from source files on my PC)