# csv to json in specific format python

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I have a csv file:

```
Year , To , From , Number 
2005 , A  , G    , 10
2005 , B  , E    , 20
2005 , A  , F    , 30
2006 , C  , D    , 40
2006 , D  , F    , 50
```

I am expecting to get:

```
[  
  {  
    'graph':{  
      'links':[  
        {  
          'target':'A',
          'value':10,
          'source':'G'
        },
        {  
          'target':'B',
          'value':20,
          'source':'E'
        },
        {  
          'target':'A',
          'value':30,
          'source':'F'
        }
      ],
      'nodes':[  
        {  
          'name':'A',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'B',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'E',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'F',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'G',
          'node':index
        }
      ]
    },
    'year':2005
  },
  {  
    'graph':{  
      'links':[  
        {  
          'target':'C',
          'value':40,
          'source':'D'
        },
        {  
          'target':'D',
          'value':50,
          'source':'F'
        }
      ],
      'nodes':[  
        {  
          'name':'C',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'D',
          'node':index
        },
        {  
          'name':'F',
          'node':index
        }
      ]
    },
    'year':2006
  }
]
```

## **I tried implementing the code below:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dict = []
link = {
    "source":"",
    "target":"",
    "value":""
}
node1 = {
    "node": "",
    "name": ""
}
node2 = {
    "node": "",
    "name": ""
}
collection = {"year":"", "graph":{
    "nodes":[],
    "links":[]
}}
gd = df.groupby("Year")
for name, group in gd:
    group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
    newC["year"] = group["Year"]
    for i in range(0, len(group)):
        node1["name"] = group["To"][i]
        node2["name"] = group["From"][i]
        link["value"] = group["Number"][i]
        link["source"] = group["From"][i]
        link["target"] = group["To"][i]
        collection["graph"]["nodes"].append(node1)
        collection["graph"]["nodes"].append(node2)
        collection["graph"]["links"].append(link)
    dict.append(collection)
print(dict)
```

But this is the output of the collection:

```
{  
  'graph':{  
    'links':[  
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      },
      {  
        'target':'D',
        'value':50,
        'source':'F'
      }
    ],
    'nodes':[  
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'D'
      },
      {  
        'node':'',
        'name':'F'
      }
    ]
  },
  'year':0  2006  1  2006  Name:Year,
  dtype:int64
}
```

It is obviously wrong. Why does the output repeats the last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you append link/node into the collection, Python will only create a "reference" pointing to link/node (i.e., it did not fully copy the content in link/node, see [Add an object to a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196956/add-an-object-to-a-python-list)). Therefore, in the following iteration, the content in collection will change as link/node changes.

The following simple codes demonstrated this phenomenon in Python:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(3):
    link["source"] = i 
    mylist.append(link)
    print(mylistA)
```

where `link` is the same as in your code. The outputs were as follows.

```
[{'source': 0, 'target': '', 'value': ''}]
[{'source': 1, 'target': '', 'value': ''}, {'source': 1, 'target': '', 'value': ''}]
[{'source': 2, 'target': '', 'value': ''}, {'source': 2, 'target': '', 'value': ''}, {'source': 2, 'target': '', 'value': ''}]
```

To avoid this, you can simply use `copy`, i.e., when appending, always appending a deepcopy of the corresponding object. Using the same example, the resulted code (only showing the changed line, other lines are the same) looked like:

```
mylist.append(copy.deepcopy(link))
```

After the change, you will get the desired results.